# Why is my AWS free tier giving me charges for IPV4?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

[Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KxqX.png)
This is my Bill check.
I understand that I will be charged 0.5$ every month from Route53, since I am using my own domain.
But I am not sure why I'm getting charges for "$0.005 per In-use public IPv4 address per hour"

I just want to pay 0.5$ for the domain connection.
Why am I getting charged for using IPv4, and is there a way to get rid of extra charges??

[Updated Terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmyR8.png)
I have noticed that the terms have been changed, but isn't it okay for Free tier usage?

Comment: It is saying that your account used an IPv4 address for 23 hours. This is likely related to an Amazon EC2 instance you launched. Charges for IPv4 addresses is quite recent but, as @diplip mentions below, there are 750 hours of "in-use public IPv4 address usage" included in the AWS Free Tier. Perhaps you had an EC2 instance that was Stopped for 23 hours, but still with an IPv4 address attached? We can't really help you much without having more information about what was used in your AWS Account. Perhaps take a look in the EC2 section of the bill?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this news](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/), AWS started charging for IPV4 addresses from Feb 1, 2024.

But still, they've [provided 750 hrs of free IPV4](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/02/aws-free-tier-750-hours-free-public-ipv4-addresses/) usage in the free tier.

If you're being charged for the IPV4 then you're not under the free tier.

To check for which resources (IP Addresses) you're being charged, use [IPAM](https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ipam/home#PublicIpInsights)